# SSHD on Windows8 won't start: System error 1068 has occurred

Tags: windows-8, cygwin, sshd

I just installed cygwin and `ssh-host-config -y` on two new laptops running Windows8-Home. On one of them, sshd starts, on the other it doesn't:

```
C:\> net start sshd
System error 1068 has occurred.
```

This is described by Dan Regan in the cygwin blog on [this cygwin project mailing list item](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-09/msg00101.html). The problem seems to be related to logging in and the NetLogon service, but wasn't fully resolved.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen a few blogs out there that raise this problem but I couldn't comment on them so I've decided to create my own question here and answer it myself.

When I opened up the Services applet on both machines and compared the entries, the user account that service was running as differed.

The working sshd used the id .\cyg_server
The broken sshd used the id MY-HOSTNAME\cyg_server.

Changing the broken login to .\cyg_server fixed it.

Also, "[Cygwin sshd did not start due to a logon failure](https://superuser.com/questions/485460)" suggests using a more modern script, `cyglsa-config` to install cygwin but I did not try that.