# Restarting a service leads to system error 1069

Tags: windows, services, tomcat

Assume there is a service *myTomcat* running with Service Principal Name *notMe* which I want to restart. I tried the following

```
C:\me\myTomcat>net stop myTomcat
The Apache Tomcat 8.0 tomcatSecure service is stopping.
The Apache Tomcat 8.0 tomcatSecure service was stopped successfully.

C:\me\myTomcat>net start myTomcat
System error 1069 has occurred.
The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

In the GUI of services, everything in the context menu except "Start" is grayed out, so I decided for the hard way to remove the process:

```
C:\me\myTomcat>service.bat uninstall myTomcat
Removing the service 'myTomcat' ...
Using CATALINA_BASE:    "C:\me\myTomcat"
The service 'myTomcat' has been removed
```

This obviously disables the services since it is marked for deletion. When I now try to restart the service, the error still appears.

To get the service fully removed, I can remove the respective key in the registry (and maybe reboot on top of that), but this is not a procedure I want to do every time I have to restart the service. Therefore my question: **What is the clean way of restarting a service with different SPN?**

**PS:** I started the service with the command lines below. These are equivalent to starting a service as local user *me* and then changing the user via the tab "Log on" via the "Properties" entry of the context menu of the service.

```
G:\myTomcat>net start myTomcat
G:\myTomcat>sc.exe config "myTomcat" obj= "myDomain\notMe password="notMePwd"
```

Related posts:

- [Cygwin sshd did not start due to a logon failure](https://superuser.com/questions/485460/cygwin-sshd-did-not-start-due-to-a-logon-failure)

Comment: I've added more edits

Comment: I tried to clarify my question further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
A. In Windows, navigate to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services.
    B. Right-click on the wherever you have TOMCAT service; select Properties.
    C. Switch to the Log On tab.
    D. Enter the password for the listed account in both the 'Password' and 'Confirm password' boxes. It may be necessary to check if the password was recently changed. Click OK.
```

--- The user Needs to have LOGON AS SERVICE permissions

If you user group/user has not been setup that way :

```
1.Logon to the computer with administrative privileges. 
2.Open the ‘Administrative Tools’ and open the ‘Local Security Policy’ 
3.Expand ‘Local Policy’ and click on ‘User Rights Assignment’ 
4.In the right pane, right-click ‘Log on as a service’ and select properties. 
5.Click on the ‘Add User or Group…’ button to add the new user. 
6.In the ‘Select Users or Groups’ dialogue, find the user you wish to enter and click ‘OK’ 
7.Click ‘OK’ in the ‘Log on as a service Properties’ to save changes. 
Notes:
•Ensure that the user which you have added above is not listed in the ‘Deny log on as a service’ policy in the Local Security Policy.
```

To create a Windows Service from an executable for TOMCAT, you can use sc.exe:

```
sc.exe create <new_service_name> binPath= "<path_to_the_service_executable>"
```

Taken from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable

Or as a alternative use : Use NSSM( the non-Sucking Service Manager ) to run a .BAT or any .EXE file as a service.

http://nssm.cc/

If you are using XAMPP stack or something similar they have a INSTALL_TOMCAT_AS_SERVICE.BAT file in drive:\XAMPP\tomcat.

Comment: Hi, what you described in the first part (as taken from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable) above, dExIT, exactly is the (GUI way) of what my initial start-up command-line does (my user *notMe* has indeed the permissions to logon as a service). My question is rather about on **re**starting, the system error 1069 appears when trying to start it the 2nd time, i.e. my problem is probably the way I am stopping the service.

Comment: I have had the same issue when trying to do local edit on a AD account, is this in a AD domain ? If so LogonAsService permissions need to be added in the AD for that account.